# How to fetch JSON data from DB?

Tags: javascript, json, csv, pull

I've prepared a JavaScript visualization code, the visualization works via simple HTTP server, since all the necessary data are in one folder. However, I couldn't get it to work if the data input needs to be fetched from a database (now JSON file).

I've loaded the below sample data (csv file) into teradata database.

```
|x1. . . . . |y1. . . . .|z1. . . . . |x2. . . . . |y2. . . . .|z2. . . . . |
|-0.858927763|0.121607854|-0.067815693|-0.100387679|0.142522011|-0.085021698|
|0.759678102 |1.670849337|0.389506443 |-0.841098362|0.745253687| 0.07724956 |   
|1.617835159 |0.671663712|0.676541754 |-0.086900337|1.162505997| 0.822100957|
|1.878302821 |0.985942302|1.756579077 |-0.418153016|2.471764891| 0.234493023|
```

[Sample Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BY4zz.jpg)

The documentation of teradata tool stated that to access the data, index.html code must have message handler using:

```
$(window).on('message', handler)
```

and the data can be accessed inside the handler using:

```
event.originalEvent.data
```

In my local server, the JavaScript code that fetches data from csv goes like this:

```
<script>
    Plotly.d3.csv('3d-scatter.csv', function(err, rows){
  function unpack(rows, key) {
      return rows.map(function(row) 
      { return row[key]; });
  }
</script>
```

I just wanted to know what code should I be using to fetch and convert JSON data (previously '3d-scatter.csv', now a JSON data in a database) that is pulled from event.originalEvent.data handler.

---

I found the handler containing data.

Under 'message' event handler: data can be found in this path (.handler.elem.visJson.data)

So when I call visJson.data, the console outputs an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the browser [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). The `fetch()` global function can obtain resources from the network, returning a `Promise` of the HTTP response.

Use it like this:

```
fetch("http://host/endpoint.json")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    // data is an array of object, 
    // iterate over it and create an in-memory CSV
    // or verify if Plotly.d3 can be fed directly this array
  })
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.